# Changing the color of the first row of a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to style an HTML table within Power Automate. I am using the following CSS styling, what I want to do is change the color of the first row. The table I am using is copied from excel and pasted into the description of my task list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant top your problem  belongs into your question in text form and properly formatted; please DO NOT show “images of code” instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add picture of your code, but your code direct in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I write you a simple code how to access to the first row of a table:

```css
table > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
        first row
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        second row
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```